# How to convert JsonSchema Path to equivalent jsonPath within a document adhering to that schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, jsonpath

What are the possible ways to convert a JSON path written for JsonSchema to another jsonPath to refer to the same node in the generated document using the same schema?

Consider the following document:

```
{
  myObject: {
    myKey: "myValue"
   }
}
```

Which has the following schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "myObject": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "myKey": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "myKey"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "myObject"
  ]
}
```

Within the document, the path expression for myKey would be:

```
$.myObject.myKey
```

But within the schema, the path expression for myKey would be:

```
$.properties.myObject.properties.myKey
```

If I have a schema but want to generate a path expression for working with a document, how do we approach this problem?

At first glance, it might appear a simple string replacement would suffice.  But once I have a property named "properties" or an array named "items", it starts to become interesting.

Comment: One way is a string manipulation.

Comment: @ThomasSablik what would be the logic to manipulate that string

Comment: Do you have an example?